# mysql output two columns for data in one column

Tags: mysql

I've reached the limits of the very little sql knowledge I have.

I have a table with firewall log data in it. There is a column called action that is either 'allowed' or 'dropped' I'd like to output summary data so I can graph allowed vs. dropped over time in gnuplot. I can do this to get a count for allowed or denied:

```
mysql> select date_format(timestamp,'%H:%i:%s') as timestamp, count(action) as denied from events where timestamp >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00' and timestamp <= '2013-11-01 01:00:00'   and action='dropped' GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 300 limit 3;
+-----------+--------+
| timestamp | denied |
+-----------+--------+
| 00:00:35  |    165 |
| 00:05:07  |    124 |
| 00:10:07  |     57 |
+-----------+--------+
3 rows in set (6.80 sec)
```

Or this for allowed:

```
mysql> select date_format(timestamp,'%H:%i:%s') as timestamp, count(action) as allowed from events where timestamp >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00' and timestamp <= '2013-11-01 01:00:00'   and action='allowed' GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 300 limit 3;
+-----------+---------+
| timestamp | allowed |
+-----------+---------+
| 00:00:00  |    2392 |
| 00:05:00  |    2310 |
| 00:10:00  |    2029 |
+-----------+---------+
3 rows in set (7.29 sec)
```

What I would like is an output like this:

```
+-----------+--------+---------+
| timestamp | denied | allowed |
+-----------+--------+---------+
| 00:00:35  |    165 |    2392 |
| 00:05:07  |    124 |    2310 |
| 00:10:07  |     57 |    2029 |
+-----------+--------+---------+
```

I tried a union but that seems to mix the data together in two columns:

```
mysql> select timestamp, count(action) as allowed from events where timestamp >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00' and timestamp <= '2013-11-01 00:59:59' union all select timestamp, count(action) as denied from events  where timestamp >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00' and timestamp <= '2013-11-01 23:59:59' and action='dropped';
+---------------------+---------+
| timestamp           | allowed |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2013-11-01 00:00:00 |   54254 |
| 2013-11-01 00:00:35 |   31788 |
+---------------------+---------+
2 rows in set (13.77 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT date_format(TIMESTAMP, '%H:%i:%s') AS TIMESTAMP, 
SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'dropped' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS denied,
SUM(CASE WHEN action = 'allowed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS allowed 
FROM events
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
  AND TIMESTAMP <= '2013-11-01 01:00:00'
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP) DIV 300 limit 3;
```

This will SUM 1 for every time the CASE WHEN validation is true, 0 otherwise. This should get you the results you are looking for, as for the GROUP BY, i'm not sure what you are trying to do there, so i left it as it was.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! FWIW, the group by was to grouup the time stamps in 5min intervals.